# SQL Server stored procedure - Insert syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I am trying to create a stored procedure to store data input from web forms to a SQL Server table. I can get the select statement for `first_name` to work correctly, but when I try add more Insert statements, I get a syntax error.

What am I doing wrong? Screenshot below. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Looks like Microsoft SQL Server, from the use of square brackets. It's common for users of Microsoft SQL Server to call their RDBMS simply "SQL" as if there's no other implementation of the SQL language. I bet if they used a text editor, they'd call it "Word."

Comment: Microsoft SQL management studio 2017 (sorry i should have specified)

Comment: Edit the tags of your question to be more clear. Using tags appropriately helps you get answers from the people who know that product best, because they search for questions posted using that tag.  [tag:sql-server] is the most common tag for Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: You have a comma before the first closing parent.  Typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the comma `,` before parantheses.

```
@email_email varchar(50),
                       ^^^
```

besides I believe that your insert statement is needed to be like

```
insert into dbo.users (first_name, last_name, email)
   values (@first_name, @last_name, @email_email)
```